# TypeScript issue with node-fetch and trying to omit some properties from RequestInit

Tags: typescript, node-fetch

I'm quite new to TypeScript

I'm trying to write a wrapper around making a post request that looks like

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

async function post(
    address: string,
    url: string,
    body: any,
    headers?: Record<string, string>,
    otherParams?: Omit<RequestInit, 'body' | 'method' | 'headers'>
) {
    const response = await fetch(
        `${address}${url}`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
            headers: headers,
            ...otherParams
        }
    );
    return await response.json()
}
```

The intent is to have this as a convenient and easy to use wrapper, so it doesn't show right away what `otherParams` are accepted (because in most cases they won't be necessary), but if a developer wants to check and use them - they can.

The above compiles fine. But I realised that we don't really need `headers` there, so we moved to something like this (just removing mentions of headers from above):

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

async function post(
    address: string,
    url: string,
    body: any,
    otherParams?: Omit<RequestInit, 'body' | 'method'>
) {
    const response = await fetch(
        `${address}${url}`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
            ...otherParams
        }
    );
    return await response.json()
}
```

This however fails compilation with the following error:

```
minimal-breaking-example.ts:12:9 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ signal?: AbortSignal; window?: null; referrer?: string; headers?: HeadersInit; cache?: RequestCache; credentials?: RequestCredentials; ... 6 more ...; body: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestInit'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'HeadersInit' is not assignable to type 'import("<my local path>/node_modules/node-fetch/@types/index").HeadersInit'.
      Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HeadersInit'.
        Type 'Headers' is missing the following properties from type 'Headers': entries, keys, values, raw, [Symbol.iterator]

 12         {
            ~
 13             method: 'POST',
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
... 
 15             ...otherParams
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 16         }
    ~~~~~~~~~
```

Maybe someone has some ideas on what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, while writing the question, I actually figured it out. I'm making a note here in case someone else stumbles upon this.

I noticed that when I remove the import from `node-fetch`, everything works properly. I also noticed that it specifically for type `Header`, it says it's missing properties: `entries`, `keys`, `values`, `raw`, `[Symbol.iterator]`.

Turned out that the `RequestInit` type expected by `fetch` and the global `RequestInit`, which I've been using to create the new type with `Omit`, are actually two different types. `fetch` redefines the global types extending them with a few properties. Interestingly, the properties added to `RequestInit` are all optional, however the ones added to `Headers` are not. The `fetch.Header` type requires, above all the properties from the global `Header`, that `entries`, `keys`, `values`, `raw`, `[Symbol.iterator]` are present ([node-fetch Headers](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/1c5ed6b981e6c5dd28bd50f5ab5418e5bd262b99/@types/index.d.ts) vs [fetch Headers](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b24b6a1125321fb62d53dd544a6c59f03a6eac07/lib/lib.dom.d.ts)).

The solution here is to use `fetch.RequestInit` instead of `RequestInit`, i.e. this works just fine:

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { RequestInit } from 'node-fetch';

async function post(
    address: string,
    url: string,
    body: any,
    otherParams?: Omit<RequestInit, 'body' | 'method'>
) {
    const response = await fetch(
        `${address}${url}`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
            ...otherParams
        }
    );
    return await response.json()
}
```